# VB: SQL Query return result to textbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

In short, I am working on a program that will add/edit entries to an SQL database.

One of the features for this program is that it, if given the account ID number, will look up the name under that account with that given ID. This is what I am having trouble with.

General Format:

- Objective: SQL Query that will return string to textbox
- AcctID => field in table with account number
- AcctName => field in table with account name
- txtbx_accountName => textbox I need the name returned to

NOTE:

- This is all nested in a generic Try-Catch statement with error
  handling.
- This is all inside a Click event handler for a button.
- This is all done in Visual Studio 2015

```vb
Dim myConn As New SqlConnection
Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand

myConn.ConnectionString = ""
myConn.Open() ' Open the connection
myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand()

' Build the query with the account number as paramter
myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT AcctName FROM DataSetTable WHERE (AcctID = @incomingAcctID)"
' Add the parameter so the SqlCommand can build the final query
myCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@incomingAcctID", (CInt(txtbx_accountNum.Text))))

' run the query and obtain a reader to get the results
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

' check if there are results
If (reader.Read()) Then
    ' populate the values of the controls
    txtbx_accountName.Text = reader(0)
End If

' Close all connections
myCmd.Dispose()
myConn.Close() ' Close connection
myConn.Dispose()
```

Comment: For future reference: please explain the "troubles" that you have - what do you want to see happening (filled textbox in this case) and what *did* you see?

Comment: Since I had the statements above in a generic Try-Catch statement with error handling, I got errors similar to "connection property has not been initialized" and "format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0", but these varied depending on what changes I made to the connection string. Those changes I cannot recall now. Bottom line, the answer I provided below works, so do not "down-vote" it.

Answer (score 0):

i am not pro but i do like this,sorry if this not helped you:

if your Stored procedure is created to add and edit than write this and call it where you want to add:

```
    private sub NAME(ByVAL Parameter1 name as integer,
                     ByVAL Parameter2 name as string,
                     ByVAL Parameter3 name as boolean)

             Dim strConn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databaseXYZ").ConnectionString
             Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
             Dim myCmd As SqlCommand

    try
            myConn.Open()
            sqlCommand = New SqlCommand("PRCEDURE_NAME", myConn )
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            dim param as new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
            param.parameterName="@send_parameter1"
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            param.Value = send_parameter1


            dim param1 as new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
            param1.parameterName="@send_parameter2"
            param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            param1.Value = send_parameter2

            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(Param)
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(Param1)
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   catch ex as exception
      throw
   End Try 
      myConn.Close()
      myConn = Nothing
  end sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm a dummy!!!

Here is the solution, for all interested parties.

Click Event Handler (w/ nested Try-Catch):

```
txtbx_accountName.Text = DataSetTableAdapter.SearchNameQuery(CInt(txtbx_accountNum.Text)).ToString
```

SearchNameQuery:

```
SELECT AcctName FROM DataSetTable WHERE AcctID = @incomingAcctID
```

More notes on this:
 - The dataset is already included in the project